# Wake-on-LAN with encrypted drive

Tags: ubuntu, partitioning, encryption, wake-on-lan, disk-encryption

I've set up a Ubuntu system as a server, with the entire drive encrypted. It needs the password at bootup, after the BIOS hands over to GRUB (at least I think that's when).

I've since set up Wake-on-LAN, which starts the computer, which only gets as far as the drive-encryption password prompt. It doesn't get far enough to ask about login details, or to be able to ssh in.

Is there a way to enter the password remotely? If not, is there a way to boot into an unencrypted partition, and then decrypt the rest of the drive? If I need to repartition, is there a way to do it while keeping the settings etc?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a remote (network) console to do this, and I'd be reluctant to use one that I didn't trust & own (if I were you).  On the other hand, it solves your other problems too.

Comment: Sorry, what? Do you mean ssh? Or something more like VNC? Either way I would need to be able to login, but the entire disk (including the usernames/passwords in /etc/passwd) is encrypted.
I need a way to decrypt the file-system remotely.

Comment: I mean this: http://www.raritan.com/products/kvm-over-ip/kx-ii-101/

Answer (score 0):

This is my problem:
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=732069